# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular

Why do I get the error of 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined' with this code:

**html**

```
 <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="!filter">
        <div class="text-center">
          <i class="ni ni-building ni-3x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive" #unfilteredData>

        </div>
      </div>
```

**ts**

```
@ViewChild('unfilteredData', {static: true}) unfilteredData: ElementRef;
 constructor(
        private ss: StationsService,
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private as: AppointmentService,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
    ) {
        this.stations = this.ss.stations;
     }

ngOnInit() {
        this.getLocations();
    }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.onToggleChange();
}

onToggleChange() {
        if (this.filter) {
            this.showListMessage = 'Filtered';
        } else {
            this.showListMessage = 'Unfiltered';
            this.setupUnfiltered();
        }
    }

setupUnfiltered() {
       
            this.renderer.setProperty(this.unfilteredData.nativeElement, 'innerHtml', <label>XXX</label>);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From official docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description

> View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.

This means viewChild property will only be available at ngAfterViewInit (and after that)

(you are currently trying to access it in the OnInit event)

Also, you need to change static to false (since you have a structural directive [ngIf] as a parent to your viewChild reference)

[Stackblitz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lt4dwc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I think, since you have the ngIf on the parent div, you need to change the static property to false

Comment: please check the example I supplied in the edit to my answer

Comment: Hi, I tried the same solution you have provided, 
had set the @viewChild as static: false as in html the parent div has a *ngIf condition
Also the function call has been kept in ngAfterViewInit. Still the error persists
Any solution will be helpful